# Is it possible to have messages sent to Exchange go directly to folders?

Tags: exchange-2010

Some email servers support a special syntax such as `name%folder@example.com` that will deliver the message into the specified folder for that user. In the past there was mention of this type of thing on gmail using the `+` to apply labels.  This is particularly useful for IMAP.  Does anyone know if this sort of thing can be done with Exchange?

Comment: And, yes, I know I can create filters.  I was looking for this specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you could add that secondary email address with the folder name into the account and then user mail rules on the mailbox to do it.  I am not aware of anything built in that can do that without adding something to the mail server to move mail around.  I have a few scripts that move mail around from the inbox to the deleted items, but it is powershell that runs as a script for the purposes of importing data that is emailed to us.

Answer (score 0):

Even Gmail's `user+tag@gmail.com` syntax didn't automatically create folders or labels for received items. With the `+` tagging you could *more easily* create filters because of the recipient address, but it wasn't automatic.

No matter what, something has to be done on the client side (or with server-side rules perhaps) to gain this functionality.  You could consider a second account, a rule, or some form of add-on.